# Unable to import Okhttp tls to kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I am trying to import OkHttp TLS to be able to use certificates and other OkHttp TLS functionality

my `build.gradle.kts` looks like this

```
implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls")
```

However, gradle is unable to find this module

`Could not find com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls`

Unsure if okhttp tls is not imported this way any longer

Comment: The package [does exist](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-tls). It's odd that Gradle doesn't mention the version it cannot find. Are you using the okhttp bom to fix the versions?

Comment: @Augusto I am not using okhttp bom. I am going to try that and see if it fixes the find for me

Comment: @Augusto The bom seems to have fixed it. I don't have much knowledge about the bom, is it supposed to fix instances like this where the right packages can't be found?

Comment: The problem here is that there was a dependency specified, but without a version. The Bill of Materials (BOM) is a way to specify multiple dependency versions without depending on them. You don't need to use it, but it makes it easier to use some libraries that have multiple packages which might not be backwards compatible between themselves. Some very popular libraries that use this and come to my mind are are Jackson, okhttp and http4k. You can read a bit more about BOMs in the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to try the following

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
```

You can take a closer look at the [docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#releases)

```
dependencies {
   // define a BOM and its version
   implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.10.0"))

   // define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
}
```